# bootstrap daterangepicker in partial view modal not triggering

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap Modals and Partial Views in my application to load forms for the user.

I'm trying to use the daterangepicker in one of my forms and it actually works fine on Chrome, but I just can't make it to work on IE. Could someone please tell me what is wrong? Its as if IE is completly ignoring my callback function

My form in Partial View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveKPI", "Channel"))
{   
                <fieldset>
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.CampaignId)
     <div id="kpireportrange" class="pull-right" class="datepicker">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg"></i><span></span>@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.SelectedStartDate, new
                                                                                                {
                                                                                                    id = "startDate"
                                                                                                })
    <b class="caret"></b></div>

@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => Model.AttributeId, new SelectList(Model.AllAttributes, "AttributeId", "Name"), new
{
    @class = "form-control",
     @style = "width:250px"
})

Target: @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.AttributeValue, new
     {
            @class = "form-control",
                 @value = "Vul hier het aantal in..",
                 @style = "width:250px"
        })
     <br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="btnSave">
            KPI TOEVOEGEN</button>
        </fieldset>     
    }
```

Script in Partial View:

```
  $(document).ready(function ()
        {

            $('#kpireportrange span').html(moment().format('MMMM YYYY'));
            var elem = document.getElementById("startDate");
            elem.value = moment().format('MMMM YYYY');

$('#kpireportrange').daterangepicker(
    {
        ranges: {
            'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
            'Last Month': [moment().subtract('month', 1).startOf('month'), moment().subtract('month', 1).endOf('month')]
        },
        startDate: moment(),
        endDate: moment()
    },
    function (start, end)
    {
        $('#kpireportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM YYYY'));
        var elem = document.getElementById("startDate");
        elem.value = start.format('MMMM YYYY');
    }
);

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution to my issue here: https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker/issues/219

Adding this did the trick

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () {};
```

Answer (score -2):

wow ..

added above line in show.bs.modal function .. worked for me ,,

$('#aboutModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {

$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () {};

Comment: Please try and explain how your answer is different from the existing answer. If you also arrived at the same answer as the existing answer, simply upvote the existing answer. I see that you do not have enough reputation for that. But there is no benefit in adding the same answer again.